# Problema con gradle sync

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, app

Acabo de instalar `Android Studio`, y me esta dando este error todo el rato:

> ```
> Failed to resolve: com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2
> Failed to resolve: com.android.support: appcompat-v7:26
> ```

¿Alguna sugerencia de porque puede ser?

Build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.alejandro.primeraapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Agrega tu build.gradle!

Answer (score 0):

Actualiza tu versión de espresso a la 2.2.2:

```
 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
```

Revisa la documentación:

https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/setup/

En cuanto a :

```
 com.android.support: appcompat-v7:26
```

Asegura tener instalada esta versión, puedes ver en el mensaje y dar clic en `Install repository and sync proyect` para esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El primer paso creo que ya viene asi por defecto, y en cuando a lo segundo cuando clikeo en el mensaje no ocurre nada

Comment: Debería de instalar el repositorio, revisa que tengas conexión a internet.

Comment: Esta todo correcto pero no lo instala. He probado a comentar todas las lineas que provocan el error, y ahora si que me deja ejecutar la app; pero en consecuencia me aparecen otros errores

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente un error de tipo `Failed to resolve`, significa que el **gradle no encuentra el archivo** en su librería y que **tampoco pudo descargarlo**.

Comprueba si **Android Studio** tiene acceso a **Internet** y si sus componentes también lo tienen, chequea el firewall.

También comprueba en la ventana de gradle que no lo tengas en modo offline, en este modo no es capaz de descargar nada.

Por último chequea que tienes bien instalado el android-sdk y que tiene acceso a Internet.